# Python/MySQL - import csv file to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, csv, tkinter

I am developing an application that consists of selecting a file (.csv) in a directory and importing the data into it into the database (mysql), but the following error is appearing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TESTES\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/TESTES/PycharmProjects/Heiken/tess.py", line 16, in import_file
    with open(browse_file):
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not function
```

Below is the complete code with the functions, in a testing interface:

```
from tkinter import *
import pymysql
from tkinter import filedialog

tess = Tk()

def browse_file():

    fname = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Template files", "*.csv"), ("All files", "*")))
    print(fname)

def import_file():
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', password='', db='omnia')
    print('connect successfull!')

    with open(browse_file):
        statm = "INSERT INTO omniacademp(n_id, n_cod, c_cnpjcpf, c_razao, c_enderecom, c_nr, c_compl, c_cep, c_bairro, c_cidade, c_estado, c_telefone, c_email, c_celular, c_email2) VALUES (0, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(statm)
        conn.commit()



bt = Button(tess, text='browse file', command=browse_file)
bt.place(x=10, y=10)

bt = Button(tess, text='import file', command=import_file)
bt.place(x=10, y=45)


tess.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're missing the list of values to fill in all the placeholders when you call `cursor.execute()`. You're never reading from the file.

Comment: `with open(browse_file):` makes no sense. `browse_file` is a function, not a filename. If you change `browse_file()` to do `return fname` you can change this to `with open(browse_file()) as f:` and then read from `f`.

Answer (score 0):

First , you should return path from `browse_file` function. Try this :

```
from tkinter import *
import pymysql
from tkinter import filedialog

tess = Tk()

def browse_file():
    return filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Template files", "*.csv"), ("All files", "*")))

def import_file():
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', password='', db='omnia')
    print('connect successfull!')

    with open(browse_file()):
        statm = "INSERT INTO omniacademp(n_id, n_cod, c_cnpjcpf, c_razao, c_enderecom, c_nr, c_compl, c_cep, c_bairro, c_cidade, c_estado, c_telefone, c_email, c_celular, c_email2) VALUES (0, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(statm)
        conn.commit()



bt = Button(tess, text='browse file', command=browse_file)
bt.place(x=10, y=10)

bt = Button(tess, text='import file', command=import_file)
bt.place(x=10, y=45)


tess.mainloop()
```